# Allow my android application authenticate with google account

Tags: android, accountmanager

I want my users to identify with google account n my app.

i know that with `AccountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google")` i can get all google account and let the users choice one of them but if the user want use other account, how i do?

which is the correct flow for identify a user using the AccountManager?

Answer (score 1):

Use `AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent()`. It creates a dialog which lets you choose which account to use and provides functionality to create a new one.